# Find the complex integral of $f(z) = \frac{z^3e^{1/z}}{1+z^3}$ on the circle contour $|z|=3$

Tags: complex-analysis, cauchy-integral-formula

If $f(z) = \frac{z^3e^{1/z}}{1+z^3}$ and $C:=\{z \in \mathbb{c} :|z|=3\}$ be in a positive sense (anti-clockwise), then $$\int_{C}f(z)dz = $$
(a) $2\pi i$

(b) 0

(c) $-2\pi i$

(d) $-3\pi i$

Attempt:

The singularities are at the 4 points given by $z^3 =-1$ (we obtain 3 singularities from here) and $z=0$. So, the solution can be found out by Cauchy's integral formula given by $\sum_{i}2\pi i f(a_i)$ where $a_i$ denotes the singularities.

But the above mentioned method is very time consuming and won't help me in a competitive exam. Is there any other way out to solve this possibly quicker than the above mentioned way?

Please help. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The change of variable $w=\frac 1 z$ reduces the integral to $-\int_{C'} \frac {e^{w}} {w^{2}(1+w^{3})} dw$ where $C'=\{w: |w|=\frac   13\}$. Now there is only one pole. By expanding  the exponential and using the expansion of $\frac 1 {1+w^{3}}$ as $1-w^{3}-w^{6}-\cdots$ you can quickly see that the coefficint of $\frac  1 w$ is $-1$ so the answer is $-2\pi i$.

Comment: Basically on substituting $z=1/\omega$, I am getting $\int_{C'} \frac{e^{\omega}}{1+\omega^3}$ but not the $\omega^2$ in the denominator

Comment: @s1mple $dz=-\frac  1 {w^{2}}dw$